# ExtJS - Data from Store don't load

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a problem with loading data from store. Please tell me what I do wrong. I am using ExtJS 4.1. 
Request sends properly, i haven't troubles like file not found or something like that. It also works if I had few stores, and any of this stores loading one 'data type' to his model, for example urls1. But if I have one store and one big model, data don't display.

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
"root": {
    "tName": "name",
    "urls1": [{
            "url": "http:// ..... :09'"
        }, {
            "url": "http:// ..... :10'"
        }],
    "perS": "",
    "perD": "",
    "urls2": [{
            "url": "http:// ..... :0009'"
        }, {
            "url": "http:// ..... :0010'"
        }],
    "val2": "",
    "list2": [{
            "level": "lvl1"
        }, {
            "level": "lvl2"
        }],
    "types": [{
            "type": "type2"
        }, {
            "type": "type4"
        }],
    "accs": [{
            "login": "login",
            "pass": "p1",
            "port": "8858",
            "conType": "type3",
        }, {
            "login": "login3",
            "pass": "p13",
            "port": "88583",
            "conType": "type2",
        }]
}
}
```

My Model:

```
Ext.define('ACT.model.myModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {name: 'tname'},
    {name: 'urls1'}, 
    {name: 'psec'}, 
    {name: 'pday'},

    {name: 'urls2'}, 
    {name: 'list2'},
    {name: 'types'},

    {name: 'accs'}, 

]
```

});

My Store:

```
Ext.define('ACT.store.dataStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
storeId:'mStore',
model: 'ACT.model.myModel',
autoLoad: true,

proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'resources/data/configuration/MyConfig.json',
    reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'root',
    successProperty: 'success'
    }
}
```

});

and my initComponent function in view:

```
initComponent: function() {

    var me = this;

    this.columns = [
    {
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        text: ' ',
        width: 100,
        sortable: false,
        hideable: false,
        allowBlank: false
    },
    {
        text: 'URL',
        width: '85%',
        dataIndex: 'urls1',
        sortable: true,
        hideable: false
    }]
this.callParent(arguments);

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above should load `urls1` into the store correctly, however, the data type is `array`. So the data is in the store but it is only not displayed in the grid as `dataIndex` points to that array.

You can create another model for urls and [associate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association) it with the master model.